# Force MediaRecorder to produce AAC LC

Tags: android, audio, aac

I am recording audio on Android. Here is a relevant snippet

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

However, the resulting adts file is recorded with AAC LTP (Long Term Prediction) object type. Is there any way to force MediaRecorder to produce AAC LC on all devices which support it?

Comment: I've got a similar problem.  I'm using the ExoPlayer to play streaming audio. It can handle audio encoded with AAC_LC but not AAC LTP.  Samples recorded with AAC LTP do not play in the chrome app for Android either; the exoplayer team says AAC LTP is not a supported format.  I believe these samples were recorded on Android; which would mean that Android is recording content it cannot play.  There is another AudioEncoder option, AAC_ELD, which stands for Enhanced Low Delay; if that only produced AAC LC that would solve our problems. However, from its description it sounds like it won't help

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the media framework that incorrectly tags ADTS files as having the LTP object type, when it's actually LC. Such files then get rejected on playback because Android doesn't support LTP.
If you record using the THREE_GPP fileformat instead, the recording will be fine.